# Mysql Select query takes too long for mutilple tables - 12 minutes

Tags: mysql

Mysql query almost takes more than 12 minutes though indexing is in place. Please can you throw some light on how to bring down the response time. Thanks

```
select count(*) 
from IMSI t1 USE INDEX(imsi_index),
StdSubServiceProfile t4 USE INDEX(msisdn_mode),
Auc t3 
where t1.mSubIdentificationNumberId=t3.mSubIdentificationNumberId and    
      t1.mobileNetworkCodeId=t3.mobileNetworkCodeId and 
      t1.mobileCountryCodeId=t3.mobileCountryCodeId and 
      t4.associatedMainMsisdn=t1.mainMSISDN and 
      t3.authenticationSubscriberType=1 and 
      (t4.networkAccessMode=1 or t4.networkAccessMode=2);
```

EXPLAIN for the above query is :

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                                                                                     | rows    | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t4    | ALL    | msisdn_mode   | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                                                                    | 2374015 | Using where with pushed condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref    | imsi_index    | imsi_index | 13      | hlr.t4.associatedMainMsisdn                                                             |      11 | Using where                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 12      | hlr.t1.mSubIdentificationNumberId,hlr.t1.mobileNetworkCodeId,hlr.t1.mobileCountryCodeId |       1 | Using where                       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+

INDEX for the table t1:

+-------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name                | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| IMSI  |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | mSubIdentificationNumberId | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |
| IMSI  |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | mobileNetworkCodeId        | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |
| IMSI  |          0 | PRIMARY    |            3 | mobileCountryCodeId        | NULL      |     2374031 |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |
| IMSI  |          1 | imsi_index |            1 | mainMSISDN                 | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

Index for the table t4 :

+----------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name              | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| StdSubServiceProfile |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | gsmServiceProfileId      | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |
| StdSubServiceProfile |          0 | PRIMARY     |            2 | suMSubscriptionProfileId | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |
| StdSubServiceProfile |          0 | PRIMARY     |            3 | suMSubscriberProfileId   | NULL      |     2374015 |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |
| StdSubServiceProfile |          1 | msisdn_mode |            1 | associatedMainMsisdn     | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| StdSubServiceProfile |          1 | msisdn_mode |            2 | networkAccessMode        | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+----------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: How many rows re returned by this query?

Answer (score 1):

As you see from the explain output, mysql does a full table scan on table t4 (rows: 2374015, keys: NULL).

Adding an index just for networkAccessMode will probably help - depending on the value diversity in networkAccessMode.

How does the explain change when you don't specify the indices explicitly?